# R + ggplot: geom_txt label not recognize a variable in function call

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, label, lm

I'm an R/ggplot newbie switching over from MatLab.

I would like to create a function using ggplot with linear regression equation printed on the graph (which is discussed in  [Adding Regression Line Equation and R2 on graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/ggplot2-adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph/7549819#7549819)). But here, I am trying to build a function with it but wasn't successful.

I kept getting an error - 
"Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'label' not found".

One workaround is to define "label" variable  outside of the function but I just don't understand why this doesn't work.

Can anyone explain why?

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:100))
df$y <- 2 + 3 * df$x + rnorm(100, sd = 40)

f <- function(DS, x, y, z) {
    label <- z
    print(label)

    ggplot(DS, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
        geom_point() +
        labs(y=y) +
        labs(title=y) +
        xlim(0,5)+
        ylim(0,5)+
        geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)+
        geom_text (aes(x=1, y=4, label=label))
}

f(df, x, y, "aaa") #execution line
```

Answer (score 5):

See the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:100))
df$y <- 2 + 3 * df$x + rnorm(100, sd = 40)
f <- function(DS, x, y, z) {
  label.df = data.frame(x=1, y=4, label=z)
  ggplot(DS, aes_string(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point() +
    labs(y=y) +
    labs(title=y) +
    geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)+
    geom_text (aes(x=x, y=y, label=label), label.df)
}

f(df, "x", "y", "aaa")
```

There were a few fixes about your code:

- The data you are using in `geom_text` is the same you have defined in `ggplot()` unless you change it. Here I have created a temporary `data.frame` for this purpose called `label.df`.
- The `xlim()` and `ylim()` functions were filtering most of your data points, since the range of `x` and `y` are much larger than the limits you defined in the original code.
- When you want to pass the names of the columns of your `data.frame` to be used for displaying the graph it would be easier to pass their names as strings (i.e. `"x"`). This way, the `aes()` function is also changed to `aes_string()`.

Here is the result:
[image]

**Edit**
Thanks to @Gregor, a simpler version would be:

```
f <- function(DS, x, y, z) {
   ggplot(DS, aes_string(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point() +
    labs(y=y) +
    labs(title=y) +
    geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE)+
    annotate(geom="text", x=1, y=4, label=z)
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what was the problem?

Comment: I'd recommend `annotate(geom = "text", ...)` rather than `geom_text`. Avoids the hassle of creating a new data frame.

Comment: Also, you don't need to pass x and y in the function. You just pass the data frame and ggplot gets x and y from DS.

Comment: @eipi10 passing those arguments makes the function more flexible. Just think that the columns have different names than "x" and "y".

Comment: Thanks @Gregor. I was able to reproduce the plot using "annotate". Thanks Ali.  I corrected my x and ylimit which was used for old df and I also noted use of "" in the function execution.